# vim PluginInstall not working in linux how to install plugins

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

this is my vimrc file in ~/ folder

**Note : i use linux (kali linux)**

`https://pastebin.com/i37cPUSK`

i installed vim plug using this

`curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs`

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim`

[iam getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNc6u.png) i tried enter `:PluginInstall` it shows not an editor command
i even tried `:PlugInstall`

but it's not working you can see my vimrc file from above link i didn't posted because it will be too messi

Comment: I would open the file with config (plug.vim or whatever it is) and do :so there, then try :PlugInstall

Comment: worth a try, I am coming from Packer with neovim (lua config files), but I guess it could be similar with Plug

Comment: so the config and the commands might not be autoloaded every time you open vim, but rather you need to shoutout the file to activate them (activate the package manager)

Comment: If you have trouble installing plugins with vim-plug, then use vim-plug's issue tracker.

Comment: looked at instructions and probably my idea won't work. Wish you good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your .vimrc might be corrupt. I recommend removing it (`rm ~/.vimrc`) and opening a new file using vim (`vim ~/.vimrc`) and pasting the config from the raw version of your pastebin (https://pastebin.com/raw/i37cPUSK).

I just tried the same in a new Docker container and it seems to work fine. Here are the steps that worked:

```bash
# Download Ubuntu image.
docker pull ubuntu

# Start a new container.
docker run -it --rm --name ubuntu-vim ubuntu:latest

# Install vim, curl, and git, and tools to check/change line endings.
apt-get update && apt install -y vim curl git file dos2unix

# Install vim-plug.
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim

# Install jellybean (because you have it in your .vimrc).
curl -fLo ~/.vim/colors/jellybeans.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/master/colors/jellybeans.vim

# Remove any existing .vimrc file.
rm -f ~/.vimrc

# Download your .vimrc.
curl -fLo ~/.vimrc https://pastebin.com/raw/i37cPUSK

# Ensure correct line endings for Unix.
dos2unix ~/.vimrc

# Install plugins non-interactively.
vim +'PlugInstall --sync' +qa
```

Comment: Can I use this for same thing for Kali Linux ( not ubuntu ) thanks for the help

Comment: @MdNihal05 - Yes, it is the exact same command for Kali. If you want to test with Docker, just change the first two commands to: `docker pull kalilinux/kali-rolling` and `docker run -it --rm --name kali-linux-vim kalilinux/kali-rolling:latest` then execute all the other commands and it should work as expected.